# Android Spinner Color style

Tags: android, spinner, android-styles, picker

Is there a way of changing the color of the Spinner control?
For example, Android 6 will render text with an arrow. I need to change the color of that arrow.

> The change should apply to any version of android.

For example, Android 4 has underline with corner triangle. I have seen some approaches where you replace the icon that is being drawn, but that solution would not work for me. I need to change the color of the default icon.

[image]

*Update*

I have found how to apply style on Android Spinner using styles.xml,

```
  <item name="android:spinnerStyle">@style/SpinnerItem</item>
```

but I cannot find what is the correct style to apply for the icon color to change.

Comment: Are you using the AppCompat library?

Comment: No this is part of a ReactNative project, so the android is plain

Comment: You want to follow this guide https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38921492/how-to-style-the-standard-react-native-android-picker/39141949#39141949

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out, there is no nice way of doing this. It is possible to change the images used for the spinner, but then I would need to provide different set of images for each version, and also have conditionals / logic on the android code, to specify which set should be used based on version.

Comment: So is this the solution?

Comment: I did not find another approach.